# Problema al almacenar datos con php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Muy buenas a todos. Me acabo de encontrar con un problemilla, espero que me podáis resolver la vida.
Tengo una clase en el que estoy creando diferentes métodos para facilitar el manejo de la base de datos. Os dejo el código de los métodos:

```
    public function conectar() {
        $this->conexion = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
        $this->conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        if($this->conexion->connect_error)
            echo "<p>La conexion falló: " . $this->conexion->connect_error . "</p>";
    }

    public function desconectar() {
        mysqli_close($this->conexion);
    }

    public function query_insert($tabla, array $valor) {
        foreach($valor as $campo=>$resultado) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO $tabla ($campo) VALUES ('$resultado')";
            if ($this->conexion->query($query) !== true) {
                echo "<p>Ha ocurrido un error: " . $this->conexion->error . "</p>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Y aquí os dejo la llamada a las funciones:

```
    $this->conectar();
    $valores = array(
        "nombre"=>"Miguel",
        "precio"=>24.15,
        "descripcion"=>"Texto más largo"
    );
    $this->query_insert("prueba", $valores);
    $this->desconectar();
```

El problema surje cuando en la base de datos, en la tabla "prueba", en lugar de almacenar una única fila almacena 3, la primera únicamente con el valor en el campo "nombre", la segunda en el campo "precio" y la tercera en el campo "descripción". ¿Alguna idea de cómo resolver esto? Muchísimas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas creando tres `INSERT` con el `foreach`.  Puedes hacerlo mas eficiente utilizando `implode()` asi:

```
public function query_insert($tabla, array $valor) {
    $campos = array_keys($valor);;
    $valores = array_values($valor);
    $campo = implode(',',$campos);
    $resultado = implode("','",$valores);
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tabla ($campo) VALUES ('$resultado')";
    if ($this->conexion->query($query) !== true) {
        echo "<p>Ha ocurrido un error: " . $this->conexion->error . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que estás insertando dentro de un bucle que recorre el array por cada valor, cuando ese array representa una sola fila.

Hay una solución simple (pero no óptima*), que consistiría en extraer las llaves del array por un lado y los valores por otro para armar una inserción única usando `implode`.

```
public function query_insert($tabla, array $valor) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tabla (".implode(",", array_keys($valores)).") VALUES ('".implode("','",array_values($valores))."')";
    #Resto del código
}
```

(*) Esta solución no es óptima en el sentido de que deberías implementar consultas preparadas para este caso, porque de lo contrario te expones a ataques de *Inyección SQL.*